# Navigation between two VIPER Routers doesn't work unless I dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a feature where I aim to open one VIPER module inside another VIPER module. But it only works if I use "dismiss", which I don't want to do. I'd like to be able to embed one VIPER module on top of another.

Here's my code:

VIPER 1 - ROUTER

```
@objc func openAnotherVC(_ notification: Notification) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //self.viewController?.dismiss(animated: true) // only works if I dismiss, I don't want to do that
        self.goToAnotherVC()
    }
}

func goToAnotherVC() {
    guard let anotherVC = AnotherVCRouter.createModule().controller else { return }
    self.viewController?.present(anotherVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

VIPER 2 - ROUTER

```
class AnotherVCRouter: AnotherVCRouterProtocol {

    var controller: UIViewController?

    static func createModule() -> AnotherVCRouterProtocol {
        let router = AnotherVCRouter()
        let view = AnotherVC(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        let interactor = AnotherVCInteractor()
        let presenter = AnotherVCPresenter(view: view, interactor: interactor, router: router)

        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: view)
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        navController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        router.controller = navController

        return router
    }

}
```

PROTOCOL

```
protocol AnotherVCRouterProtocol: AnyObject {
    var controller: UIViewController? {get set}
    static func createModule() ->AnotherVCRouterProtocol
}
```

Any help or suggestions on how to properly navigate between these VIPER modules without using "dismiss" would be greatly appreciated.